# how to create new session and preserve old session in tomcat?

Tags: session, tomcat

Now the user have many roles in his privilege, I shall allow him click href and play as another role in a new window. each role has its own session.

Since the browser open window can not open with new session, I must find a way in server side.

But request doesn't support request.createSession or request.setSession(new Session()), how can i seprate a new session for this use case?

Comment: You can't. The browser and Tomcat between them decide what a session is. Not you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new session by [HttpSession#invalidate](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29) old one but you can not retain the old one. May the following points help you

1. You've mentioned that each role has its own session
2. When user clicks a role, invalidate current session (also role) and new session would be created
3. Provide a link to go back his previous role if necessary
4. If he go backs to previous role, repeat step 2.

Comment: i think i should lets multi roles open, its very useful for user view and copypaste and do other works

Comment: why should you stick with role & session then

Comment: I think role + username = new username. this question is same to how to logon same website with two different account, each account in one tab/win of same brower. And if i let user logout and logon as another role, and logon back, all his state in browser will gone, scrollbar, selection, and others.

Answer (score 0):

You have no support from tomcat. You have to this yourself.

The next strategy **will NOT** work on clustered tomcat. No guarantees here.

**to change to a new session**

1. Walk the session attributes via `getAttributeNames()` and `getAttribute(String)` Adding them all to a `HashMap`.
2. Serialize the `HashMap` into a tempfile or a static concurrent map as something you can access latter. Also store the current `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()` for latter redirection. You **have** to serialize.
3. Walk the session attributes again and `removeAttribute(String)` them all.
4. Add the key to access the file or concurrent map to the session.
5. Redirect the user to a login page or add synthetically all authorizations needed to the session.

**to revert to old session**

1. Check if the user has a key to access the old session. If he or she does, de-serialize the `HashMap`.
2. If the de-serialization works, walk the session and `removeAttribute(String)` everything
3. Walk the `HashMap` and `setAttribute(String, Object)` on the session.
4. Redirect the user to the URL stored somehow on step 2.

I'm too lazy to write the code and test it myself but I think this will work.